# Tips for running a game with multiple characters per player

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'll start with the question before the setup: Does anyone have some good tips for running a game where players have a pool of available characters and can switch the characters they play at certain points throughout the game?

Basically, I'm about to start a new chapter of an old AD&D 2nd edition game that was shelved years ago. I've migrated the players main characters into 3.5 using Gestalt and E6 where they are already lvl6 on both tracks with no capstone or bonus feats gained yet. There will be 3 players, at most an occasionnal 4th.

The campaign ended where one of the player's character who was a noble in exile recovered his lands and title while the larger kingdom his land was part of blew up in a civil war. The other two players ran an overzealous campaign during the war and "founded" a colony on the lands of an ancient part of the kingdom that was haunted before and cleared by their actions of the former ancient undead occupants.

Powerful as they were and using the rules for followers, we had lower level followers that we're gained, statted, and sometimes played a bit by me (the DM) advancing the story.

Now I plan to play 15 years later as the civil war has torn the kingdom apart and the players are power players, their old followers occupying key positions in the kingdoms, and newer followers that will be introduced occupying other positions of powers.

And now the core of what I'm trying to achieve with this is for the players to handle their main characters, and when would come the time to split-up for various reasons (different skillset required, RP reasons or simply too many tasks to be done at once) 2 of the 3 players could leave their main character and play one of the old or new henchman.

Has anybody played a game where this kind of thing is possible? Should I be wary of the level difference between henchman and main characters as its 3 levels, even though its gestalt? Any pitfalls I should be wary of?

Comment: A request for "any tips" is way too broad for an SE question. This might belong on [a forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/15469).

Comment: This is currently too broad for a Stack site. If you can narrow your question down to be about one specific problem, it might fit here. (The line “Should I be wary of the level difference between henchman and main characters as it’s 3 levels, even though it’s gestalt?” could be a good, specific question all by itself, for example.) General tips and tricks though are best gathered [somewhere you can have a discussion](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/15469).